# Lombok how to customise getter for Boolean object field?

Tags: java, lombok

One of my POJOs has a Boolean object field to permit NULLS in the database (a requirement). Is it possible to use the @Data Lombok annotation at class level yet override the getter for the Boolean field? The default it generates is getXXX method for the Boolean field. I wish to override it as isXXX()?

Thanks,
Paddy

Comment: By definition, overriding means, writing your own getXXX for that provided by lombok. If you want to add your own isXXX, it's a different method. Why don't you create an isXXX in your POJO and in the implementation, call getXXX if required or implement it the way you like?

Comment: I have declared @Data at class level and have too many attributes in the class, so excluding getter or making the default getter private for one field will be tough. Otherwise, even if I add a isXXX method, the getXXX method will be still visible to users of the class anyway - I would rather then use the getXXX method itself. I hope you understand my context.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

It's a bit verbose, but you can provide your own `isXXX`, and then use `AccessLevel.NONE` to tell Lombok not to generate the `getXXX`:

```
@Data
public class OneOfPaddysPojos {

    // ... other fields ...

    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Boolean XXX;

    public Boolean isXXX() {
        return XXX;
    }
}
```

(And hey, at least it's not *quite* as verbose as if you weren't using Lombok to begin with!)

Answer (score 20):

I think if you switch your field from `Boolean X` to `boolean X` than lombok generate a getter `isX()` method.

Comment: True, but you need to have the field as a `Boolean` if the column is nullable on the database level. The problem is that with a primitive field (*i.e.* `boolean`) you can't really tell if a certain value is supposed to be a `NULL` or a zero (`0`). Hence OP's question.

Answer (score 13):

I know the question is old but I will leave this for future references.

You have two options to override a Getter/Setter in your class.

One is the answer from [First Option response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18139888/1970214)

The other option is to simply define the getter/setter method and lombok will not automatically produce the specified method.

I tested it myself and it seems to work fine:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProductResponse {

    private UUID id;
    private String supplierId;
    private String sku;
    private String name;
    private String brand;
    private String imgUrl;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private Float quantity;
    private String unit;
    //@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE) //This means @Data will not produce a getter for this field so have to explicitly define it
    private Set<ProductTag> tags;

    //Here we override @Data getter with a different getter (return is different type)
    public List<UUID> getTags() {
    return     tags.stream().map(ProductTag::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Here is also a reference from the development team comments: [Lombok's developer comment](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1026#issuecomment-186325559)

In my example I'm using the "override" feature for a `Collection` type but this can be used for any other type like `Boolean` in your case.

Comment: In your case it "works" because the name of your custom getter matches the name that lombok is supposed to generate. OP asks what to do if **the name doesn't match**. In their case they are `isXXX()` and `getXXX()`.

Comment: Good catch! Thanks for highlighting this which I overlooked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

what is the name of boolean field? according to the [lombok doc](http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html):

> A default getter simply returns the field, and is named getFoo if the
>   field is called foo (or isFoo if the field's type is boolean)

lombok will generate getter with name isXXX for your boolean field

Comment: You seem to be confused. The OP is obviously aware that a `boolean` field's getter will be named `isXXX()` by default; the problem is that (s)he wants that naming convention to be used for a `Boolean` field (`Boolean` being the object wrapper type for `boolean`, like what `Integer` is to `int`). (The page that you link to actually states this explicitly: "Any variation on `boolean` will *not* result in using the `is` prefix instead of the `get` prefix; for example, returning `java.lang.Boolean` results in a `get` prefix, not an `is` prefix.")

Answer (score 1):

From Lombok [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter):

> You can always manually disable getter/setter generation for any field by using the special AccessLevel.NONE access level. This lets you override the behaviour of a @Getter, @Setter or @Data annotation on a class.