# Edit lombok getter method name for boolean member having prefix "has"

Tags: java, java-8, lombok

I am having a boolean variable `hasObject` in lombok which generates `isHasObject()`. I am using `@Data` lombok annotation. How can i change the method to `hasObject()`

Comment: Consider renaming your field name. Something like `boolean objectPresent`. Then you can follow the getter/setter naming patterns and your getter would be `isObjectPresent()`.

Comment: I have to stick to "has" prefix based on the API Documentation. So I dont have that privilege.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lombok how to customise getter for Boolean object field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139678/lombok-how-to-customise-getter-for-boolean-object-field)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lombok annotation @Getter for boolean field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619986/lombok-annotation-getter-for-boolean-field)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found out help from [lombok-how-to-customise-getter-for-boolean-object-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139678/lombok-how-to-customise-getter-for-boolean-object-field).
By this I will be have the altering accessor level and the code getter old fashion,

```
@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE) private boolean hasObject;

public boolean hasObject() {
    return hasObject;
}
```

I will be keeping this question open. Is this the only way to change getter method name or I will wait for better suggestions.

Comment: Hi I voted this answer down because it changed within 5 years and @Rami s answer from May 11, 2022 is the best one (in my oppinion).

Comment: @klenkes74 I disagree with the downvote because Accessor modifies both the getter and setter when Data is used so this is still the best answer with OP's original question of modifying the getter.

Answer (score 29):

in your case it could be:

```
 class XY : Object {
      @Getter(fluent = true)
      public boolean hasObject;
 }
```

OR

```
 @Accessors(fluent = true)
 class XY : Object {
      public boolean hasObject;
 }
```

according to the docs:

> fluent - A boolean. If true, the getter for pepper is just pepper(), and the setter is pepper(T newValue). Furthermore, unless specified, chain defaults to true.
>   Default: false.

Comment: The major problem is that it doesn't apply to one variable only :-/ `@Getter(fluent=true)` doesn't work with 1.18.6.0 and the `@Accessor` is way to much cz it influences the whole class

Comment: @Getter(fluent = true) doesn't compile

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62953224/5625736 as described at this answer, Accessors can be used at a field.

Answer (score 27):

Combining the [Accessors](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors) and [Getter](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter), you might get the folllowing:

```
 class ExampleClass {
      @Accessors(fluent = true)
      @Getter
      private boolean hasObject;
 }
```

is an equivalent to the Vanilla Java:

```
class ExampleClass {
    
    private boolean hasObject;

    public hasObject() {
        return hasObject;
    }
```

Which is what you wanted, I guess.

Answer (score 9):

Just like this:

```
 @Data
 class ExampleClass {
     
      private Object data;

      @Accessors(fluent = true)
      private boolean hasObject;
 }
```

This will provide `getData()` and `hasObject()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for solution which will apply for your whole application, you can set lombook configuration `lombok.accessors.fluent` to `true`

For more informations
see https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration