# Android modify @Getter in Lombok

Tags: android, mvvm, lombok

Is there a possibility to modify Lombok's `@Getter` for one type of field? There is a MutableLiveData that is child of LiveData. I want Lombok to create getters for MutableLiveData  fields that return LiveData not MutableLiveData. I hope you understand what I mean.

To picture what I'm talking about I am adding some code:

```
public class ViewModelAccount extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> selectedLanguagesReadable = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public LiveData<String> getSelectedLanguagesReadable() {
        return selectedLanguagesReadable;
    }
}
```

It is about MVVM pattern in Android and removing boilerplate code in ViewModels. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might help you,

```
@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE) private boolean hasObject;
public boolean hasObject() {
    return hasObject;
}
```

**i found it here** [Edit lombok getter method name for boolean member having prefix "has"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669129/edit-lombok-getter-method-name-for-boolean-member-having-prefix-has)

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand how it works and what it does. Could you adjust your suggestion to my example?