# Can't override Lombok getter

Tags: java, lombok

Note: The solution referenced by a couple of people here does not work for my problem...

I have a java.sql.Timestamp field that I want to format to a String in my getter. I'm using Lombok @Data at the beginning of the class. But when I override Lombok's getter with my own getter (to format the Timestamp), the field is always null. I don't see anything in the documentation to explain this behavior.

This block of code gives me the settlementDate as a Timestamp:

```
@Data
public class MyObject {
  public Timestamp settlementDate;
}
```

This block of code gives me a NPE, because the settlementDate is null. Hmm, it just occurred to me... Could it be because the return type of the getter is different from the member type?

```
@Data
public class MyObject {
  public Timestamp settlementDate;

  String getSettlementDate() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(tradeDate);
  }
}
```

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How about this answer? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139678/lombok-how-to-customise-getter-for-boolean-object-field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139678/lombok-how-to-customise-getter-for-boolean-object-field)

Comment: I saw that, but wasn't really sure it applied to me... I'll try it though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lombok how to customise getter for Boolean object field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139678/lombok-how-to-customise-getter-for-boolean-object-field)

Comment: All you need - write one line of code `@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE) private Timestamp settlementDate;` Why you don't try it before ask, if you have seen that question?

Comment: Because I didn't think it applied to my problem.

Comment: Adding the @Getter annotation made no difference. I still get an NPE when I try to invoke getSettlementDate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's definitely some Lombok-unrelated problem with your code. Some of the following holds:

- Your field doesn't get set before the access.
- It does, but gets overwritten with `null` later.
- You're accessing it on a different thread without a visibility guarantee.

As recommended in the comments, you should create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). I usually do, and most of the time, I cancel my question as it leads me to a solution.

---

Note that writing a getter returning a type unusable with the setter is a very bad idea.

Comment: Thanks. I created a getter with a different name and now it works.

Comment: @user1660256 This is very strange.... AFAIK whenever you write your own getter, lombok skips the generation.