# Why it gives error if I try to get the value of a boolean @Transient variable using lombok?

Tags: spring, jpa

```
@Data
public class show{
    @Transient
    private boolean value;
}

show ob = new show();

ob.getValue() //throws an error
ob.isValue() //runs smoothly
```

Why is this happening? Instead of boolean, if I use Boolean, I am able to get variable's value. Why am I not able to fetch value if I use primitive datatypes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lombok annotation @Getter for boolean field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619986/lombok-annotation-getter-for-boolean-field)

Comment: Here you find details https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-getter-boolean and how to customize it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139678/lombok-how-to-customise-getter-for-boolean-object-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lombok's default behavior is to expose boolean Java methods with the prefix `isXXX()`, instead of using the `getXXX()` naming scheme.  What you are seeing is just standard behavior.

If you want to override to Lombok's default `isXXX()` naming scheme, you may provide your own getter:

```
@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)     // turn off Lombok here
private boolean value;

public boolean getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Lambok, the default getter and setter used for type `boolean` are `isValue()` and  `setValue(boolean value)` respectively. Whereas for type `Boolean` the getter and setter used are `getValue()` `setValue(Boolean value)`.

Disable Lombok for the fields you don't want by sticking `@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)` `@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)` on top of the field and write your own getters and setters